# Beating LinearAlloc issue on GingerBread and keeping jar files

Tags: android, build, jar, dex, buildpath

I'm developing a big app and I have a problem when I install it in GingerBread and Froyo devices.

> LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=1092

I know that it's because I am adding a lot of jars in my /libs folder (many Ads Network SDKs, Analytics SDK,...)

I searched a lot of articles about the subject and the better way I found to solve the problem is [here](http://birbit.com/how-to-solve-linearalloc-problem/).

Before using this, I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid unzipping jars. I mean, is it possible to exclude some jars from the /libs folder in order to exclude them from the .dex files (beating the LinearAlloc problem), and keep them in the application folders to load them at the runtime?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I solved this issue by using Proguard in my project. It works well since a few time now and I even added other library after with no issue anymore.